# Arrange unformatted paragraphs in a string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

I have a text that is unarranged say as an example

```
randstr='''
Hello Abou al Reeem
HAbibi abou lbeess
dkhlak 3amak l khil wen
Li aslan 7adan be3rif shi 3an l bazz ? 
Sara7a wala 7adan by3rif 3an l ken3an

Grave is 22 and Tony is 15
Rami is 44 and Aya is 40
'''
```

where as you can see the first paragraph is made of sentence that are splitted by `\n` different lines. What I want is to code in python such that I may end up with this instead

```
list='''
 Hello Abou al Reeem HAbibi abou lbeess dkhlak 3amak l khil wen Li aslan 7adan be3rif shi 3an l bazz ?  Sara7a wala 7adan by3rif 3an l ken3an

 Grave is 22 and Tony is 15 Rami is 44 and Aya is 40
'''
```

I was successful to a degree with my python code

```
import re
randstr='''
Hello Abou al Reeem
HAbibi abou lbeess
dkhlak 3amak l khil wen
Li aslan 7adan be3rif shi 3an l bazz ? 
Sara7a wala 7adan by3rif 3an l ken3an

Grave is 22 and Tony is 15
Rami is 44 and Aya is 40
'''

# Split the string based on empty lines (Note: I tried ^\s*$ but it did not work)
A=randstr.split('\n\n')

# Split each of the elements in A to one sentence without the \n using regular expression substitution
regex=re.compile('\n')

for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i]=regex.sub(' ',A[i])

A
```

But I was wondering if it could be any easier and if it is possible to do so in Sublime text 3 rather than on python?

Note: I am new to regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace with regex as well:

```
import re

randstr='''
Hello Abou al Reeem
HAbibi abou lbeess
dkhlak 3amak l khil wen
Li aslan 7adan be3rif shi 3an l bazz ? 
Sara7a wala 7adan by3rif 3an l ken3an

Grave is 22 and Tony is 15
Rami is 44 and Aya is 40
'''

newstr = re.sub("\n","\n\n", re.sub(r'\n(?! *\n)','',randstr)) 

print (newstr)
```

Output:

```
Hello Abou al ReeemHAbibi abou lbeessdkhlak 3amak l khil wenLi aslan 7adan be3rif shi 3an l bazz ? Sara7a wala 7adan by3rif 3an l ken3an

Grave is 22 and Tony is 15Rami is 44 and Aya is 40
```

It is essentially doing the same as COLDSPEEDs solution, first substituting

- `'\n'` not followed by optional whitespace and `'\n'` with nothing
- then replaces all remaining `'\n'` with `'\n\n'`

  r'\n(?! *\n)'  # (?! .....) is a negative lookahead - something that cant match afterwards

Comment: that is great @Patrick Artner but what if I want a '.' or a space between Reeem and HAbibi so it look like Reeem. HAbibi rather than ReemHAbibi?

Comment: @rsc05  General rule for SO.Questions: Dont pull rabbits (new things) out of nothing. Think about what you need, put **ALL** into the question. If you need 4 different things you need to adapt the regex pattern. Your question was about how to remove the single newlines - ifyou replace them with `"OOO"` instead of `""` you get `'OOO'` between all parts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions here at all. Split on two newlines, and then successively split and join each para:

```
print(
    '\n'.join(
        [' '.join(para.splitlines()) for para in randstr.split('\n\n')]
    )
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for this COLDSPEED but would it be possible to use regular expression within these lines in sublime text 3. Like may I use a keybinding code to use your code in all text in my sublime text 3?

Comment: @rsc05 I'm scratching my head here... why would you want to do that? You technically could, but I don't recommend doing so.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thank you your code is so clever but I want to know if in any circumstance which is always the case in my field I get some text that looks like that. What I am doing at the moment is I copy the text I past it into python and then I do your code. Would it be possible to use your code directly from sublime text 3?

Comment: @rsc05 Not experienced with ST plugins, but you can google "how to add python plugins to sublime text". A quick search gives me http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/plugins.html